# Error running Python program: Demystify error message

Tags: linux, python, runtime-error

So I wanted to install [ReText](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ReText/4.1~beta1), which seems to be a rather nice Markdown and reStructuredText Editor. I tried to install it from PyPI, and running `setup.py` went nicely, it all installed rather nice, but I get this error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/retext", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/retext", line 54, in main
    window = ReTextWindow()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ReText/window.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.aboutWindowTitle = self.aboutWindowTitle % app_name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'QString' and 'str'
```

Pinpointing the error to a solution is beyond me right now, I suspect it is a version issue with Qt, but I'm not sure at all about this.

OS: Fedora 19, Arch: x86_64,

Comment: It seems to be saying that the program is trying to do the modulo function of a string and a QString which is not allowed.

Comment: @ohope5 yes it is: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=28790&seqNum=2 It's a tuple/dictionary operator when used with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on Fedora 19 x84_64. There are various fallbacks for Python/Qt, so perhaps you miss some dependency?

```
sudo yum install python3-PyQt4 python3-docutils python-pyside
tar xf ReText-4.1~beta1.tar.gz
cd ReText-4.1~beta1
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/Markups-0.3 ./retext.py
```

Comment: I was missting `python3-docutils`, thanks for the hint! For some reason, Markups-0.3 installs into the python2.7/site-packages, and is always missing for Python 3. I still have to assign the path to the directory where I've unpacked Markups-0.3 to. Dumb, but I guess `setup.py` doesn't really know what to do as of yet either.